# Handling api/feed/post 404 (Not Found) and SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in Vue.js

Tags: json, api, vue.js, post, get

I'm currently building a Twitter-like page as coding practice. I'm able to fetch the JSON data and load it to the page, but when it comes to posting a new tweet, the console throws a few error messages, like `POST http://localhost:8080/api/feed/post 404 (Not Found)`, and `Backend API: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

I googled by myself and learned that a "404 error" occurs when the requested page doesn't exist, and one of the common errors when `Backend API: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` is displayed is that the "JSON" is actually HTML ect.

But I'm not sure if those alone will be helpful enough to fix my problem, so I'm posting a new one here.

One of the things that I find odd is why the JSON file is not properly processed while it does work when I just load it.

Any idea how this is happening?

Here is some parts of my code.

**[feed.json]**

```
[
  {
    "avatar": "/avatar/avatar-ivomagi.jpg",
    "username": "Ivo Mägi",
    "handle": "@ivomagi",
    "timestamp": 1543319880000,
    "content": "This is your 1500ms latency in real life situations -",
    "media": {
      "type": "video",
      "url": "https://video.twimg.com/tweet_video/DtCeK1zXcAAgQQV.mp4"
    },
    "actions": {
      "replies": 35,
      "rekweets": 2700,
      "likes": 5700
    }
  },
  {
    "avatar": "/avatar/avatar-mralancooper.jpg",
    "username": "Alan Cooper",
    "handle": "@MrAlanCooper",
    "timestamp": 1542542280000,
    "content": "We have thousands of incredibly shitty programs and apps that were shipped on time. Deadlines don’t make things better.",

    "actions": {
      "replies": 17,
      "rekweets": 393,
      "likes": 1100
    }
  },
  .........
]
```

**[App.vue]**

```
<template>
  <form class = "userContainer">
    <div class = "user-avatar">   
      <img src="avatar/avatar-loggedin.jpg">
    </div>

    <textarea rows = "10" cols = "80" v-model="kweetInput">  </textarea>    
    <p><button class = "kwitterBtn" type = "submit" @click.prevent="newKweet()">Kwitter</button></p>     
  </form>

  <button class = "JsonEx" @click="loadPage()" v-if="!pageLoaded">Show previous kweets</button>
  <button @click="hideKweets()" v-else>Hide previous kweets</button>

  <br><br>

  <div v-if="pageLoaded">   
    <show-previous-kweets v-bind:allJsonData="allJsonData"></show-previous-kweets>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ShowPreviousKweets from './components/ShowPreviousKweets';

export default {
  components: {
    'show-previous-kweets': ShowPreviousKweets
  },
  data(){
    return {
      allJsonData: [],
      pageLoaded: false,
      kweetInput: '',
      userJSON: {
        avatar: 'avatar/avatar-loggedin.jpg',
        username: 'Johan Westling',
        handle: '@johanwestling',
        timestamp: '',
        content: this.kweetInput,
        media: {
          type: '',
          url: ''
        },
        actions: {
          replies: 0,
          rekweets: 0,
          likes: 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.loadPage();
  },
  methods: {
    loadPage(){
      var self = this;

      fetch('/feed.json').then(function(response){     //    "/feed.json"      //   /api/feed/get
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(response){

        var tempArray = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
          tempArray.push(response[i]);
        }

        self.allJsonData = tempArray;
        self.setAllJsonData(self.allJsonData);

      });
      self.pageLoaded = true; 
    },
    setAllJsonData(json){
      this.allJsonData = json;
    },
    hideKweets(){
      this.pageLoaded = false;
    },
    newKweet(){
      var self = this;
      alert(self.kweetInput);

      fetch('/api/feed/post', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(self.userJSON),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then(function(backendResponse){
        console.log('backendResponse: ' + backendResponse);
        return backendResponse.json();
      }) .then((backendData) => {
        console.log('Backend API:', backendData); })
        .catch((backendResponse) => {
          console.warn('Backend API:', backendResponse);
        });

        self.kweetInput = '';
        console.log('The end of newKweet() method');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**[api.js]**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const api = express();
const apiUrl = process.env.URL || 'http://localhost';
//const apiPort = parseInt((process.env.PORT || 3001));
const apiPort = 8080;

api.use(express.json());

api.get('/api/feed/get' , (req, res) => {
  //let feedFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../employees.json');  // just an experiment with a simpler file
  let feedFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../feed.json');

  res.type('json');
  res.sendFile(feedFile);
});

api.post('/api/feed/post' , (req, res) => {
  //let feedFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../employees.json');  // just an experiment with a simpler file
  let feedFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../feed.json');
  let feedContent = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(feedFile));
  let feedPosted = req.body;
  let feedJson = '';

  console.log('/api/feed/post:', feedPosted);

  feedContent.push(feedPosted);

  feedJson = JSON.stringify(feedContent);

  fs.writeFileSync(feedFile, feedJson);

  res.type('json');
  res.sendFile(feedFile);
});

api.listen(apiPort, () => {
  console.log(`API server running at ${apiUrl}:${apiPort}`);
});
```

I'm running the program with a localhost port number 8080, so I changed the value of `const apiPort` to 8080, but it had no effect.

Another thing I found out is that when I replace `/feed.json` of the `loadPage()` method in `App.vue` with `/api/feed/get`, it stops working as well, spitting the same error message, `Backend API: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

I guess it's something wrong with `api.js`?

**[UPDATE]**

**[All the folders and files within the working directory]**

```
slutuppgift/
|-- public/                 Static files
|-- |-- index.html          HTML-code 
|-- |-- feed.json           the API JSON-data
|-- src/                
|-- |-- main.js             JavaScript-code to initialize Vue & app.vue
|-- |-- app.vue             Vue-code for the application
|-- |-- components/         Vue-code for components
|-- |-- views/              Vue-code for pages/templates (Vue-router).
|-- |-- router.js           JavaScript-code for Vue-router (URL-structure)
|-- |-- api.js              JavaScript-kod for Express.js (the API)
```

**[main.js]**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from './router';
import App from './App.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router: VueRouter,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: It sounds like you aren't making any requests to your Express server at all. The request to `feed.json` will be going directly to your Vue development server instead. You can't run both servers on port 8080, you should see an error in the server's console if you try. You need to run them on different ports and then use either proxying or CORS to overcome the cross-domain request restrictions.

Comment: ```POST http://localhost:8080/api/feed/post 404 (Not Found)``` and ```Backend API: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0``` are the all the errors that I get. Could you tell me how I can run them on a different port, when this project is already assigned the port number of 8080? I already googled key words like "Express server" etc, but still don't quite understand how they are connected to my problem. (no offence intended by "I don't understand you", rather it's because I'm still lack of a lot of background knowledge to seize the big picture)

Comment: I only have partial information on your setup so there's a high risk I'm going to confuse matters further. It appears that you have 2 servers, a Vue development server and a separate Express server for your API. These servers cannot run on the same port. How are you running the code in `api.js`? Is it pulled into something bigger or are you running it directly using Node? If that server is working you should be able to access `/api/feed/get` in a web browser just by typing the full URL into the address bar.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have 2 servers"? Does it mean I've got 2 port numbers, like 8080 and 3000? As I don't have a good big picture of what's going on, I can't answer if ```api.js``` is pulled into something bigger or running directly using Node. But I just realized that ```api.js``` might not be imported anywhere in the first place. I updated my original post, and now you should be able to see how the folders and source files are organized within the directly "slutuppgift". In this kind of structure, where and how am I supposed to import the ```api.js```?

Comment: The file `api.js` is written to run as a separate server. e.g. By running `node api.js` from the command line. I get the impression that you didn't write that file and you don't really know what it does. There are no shortcuts here, you're going to have to take the time to study that file and understand it.

Comment: I'm redoing the class assignment that I've already completed. Many of the files were prepared by the teacher beforehand, and the students were supposed to complete the entire app making the most of the files provided. When I did this earlier I only used JavaScript. The teacher gave me a passing grade, but I recently learned Vue.js, so I personally wanted to redo it. Although I don't get every single detail of what is written in ```api.js```, I still understand the main idea. Variables and functions are defined like ```api.get()```, and they are called in some other file.

Comment: So I think that what matters here is to figure out where and how to import / call the functions that were defined in ```api.js```, rather than understanding every single line of this file. The teacher advised us to use the files like ```api.js``` as sort of a "library".  Of course it'll be helpful to understand everything in this file, but it'll be difficult to do that without actually calling and using those functions.

Comment: This teacher was just a guest lecturer and he usually works at an IT company as an engineer, not as a teacher, so he is not always available for questions.